# How to get a pivot-table like result using MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, pivot

Assume we have a table in mysql:test;
how to get a result table like the pivot table in excel?

Tried to use "merge" but mysql does not support it.

Tried to use "union" but it's the index that increases but not the column.

```
select * from test;
```

Output

```
+----+------------+------+-------+
| id | date       | name | value |
+----+------------+------+-------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 | a    |     1 |
|  2 | 2019-01-02 | a    |     2 |
|  3 | 2019-01-03 | a    |     3 |
|  4 | 2019-01-04 | a    |     4 |
|  5 | 2019-01-05 | a    |     5 |
|  6 | 2019-01-06 | a    |     6 |
|  7 | 2019-01-03 | b    |     9 |
|  8 | 2019-01-04 | b    |     9 |
|  9 | 2019-01-05 | b    |     8 |
| 10 | 2019-01-06 | b    |     7 |
| 11 | 2019-01-05 | c    |     5 |
| 12 | 2019-01-06 | c    |     6 |
| 13 | 2019-01-07 | c    |     7 |
| 14 | 2019-01-08 | c    |     8 |
| 15 | 2019-01-09 | c    |     9 |
+----+------------+------+-------+
```

Wanted to get:

```
+------------+---+---+---+
| date       | a | b | c |
+------------+---+---+---+
| 2019-01-01 | 1 |   |   |
| 2019-01-02 | 2 |   |   |
| 2019-01-03 | 3 | 9 |   |
| 2019-01-04 | 4 | 9 |   |
| 2019-01-05 | 5 | 8 | 5 |
| 2019-01-06 | 6 | 7 | 6 |
| 2019-01-07 |   |   | 7 |
| 2019-01-08 |   |   | 8 |
| 2019-01-09 |   |   | 9 |
+------------+---+---+---+
```

I know it's very easy to get the result in Excel, but how to use SQL?

**Edit:**

A followed question.

What if I do NOT know what are the names in the column "name"?

That is to say, there may be a,b,c,d,e,f,g...but I do NOT know how many of distinct names are there.

How to get the result by listing all of them? ()

```
+------------+---+---+---+
| date       | a | b | c |...... and so on.
+------------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: For your second question, try changing `GROUP_CONCAT` to `SUM` in the query suggested by @James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` with `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the desired output. And good practice is to avoid reserved words like `name`, `date` , `value`

```
SELECT date,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN name='a' THEN value END) as 'a', 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN name='b' THEN value END) as 'b', 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN name='c' THEN value END) as 'c' 
FROM test GROUP BY `date`;
```

**Edit:**
It can be achieved by creating a dynamic query using `prepared statement`.

Since `value` to be summed for a column in a specific date, Sharing the query with `SUM`. You can replace with `GROUP_CONCAT` if needed.

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" SUM(CASE WHEN name='",name,"' THEN value END) AS '",name,"'")) 
INTO @pivotcol
FROM (SELECT `name` FROM test GROUP BY `name`) t;

SET @pivotquery =CONCAT("SELECT date, ",@pivotcol," from test GROUP BY `date`");

PREPARE stmt FROM @pivotquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: WOW! That's briliant!

Comment: First time use the stackoverflow and don't know how to add some codes or sql results in this comment box. I have a followered question.

Comment: If it works. Close the thread as solved. You can do by accepting the answer on left side below the down arrow a tick mark is there.. you can make only one answer as accepted.

Comment: By the way if you ask another question in the same question which was answered/unanswered not all the people can help you. Only few notices and can help you. Edit: you can edit your question too if you have more to ask.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I use sum instead of group_concat to get the satisfactory answer. I've accepted your answer, does that mean this is a solved thread? But I still have a followed question, is there any restrict that no one can comment on a solved question?

Comment: You can always ask a new one or  edit your question

Comment: I've re-edit it. And hope you can answer the followed one.

Comment: Okay, so do you need the query as `sum() or group_concat()`